# how does Clickhouse distributed query work if there is a replica of a shard doesnot have latest data

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse cluster with 10 shards, each with 2 replicas. each shard has TB data.

Now I want to add 1 replica for each shard. It will take some time to sync data from the existing replicas to the new replica because there is TB data.

Will the distributed query hit the new replica(machine) before the data syncing is completed?

Does Clickhouse have a mechanism that will skip the replica that does not have the latest data when it sends a distributed query to other shards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default replica with replication delay more 300 seconds will ignore during select

Look to 1max_replica_delay_for_distributed_queries` in documentation https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#max_replica_delay_for_distributed_queries

Also look to

```sql
SELECT hostName(), * 
FROM clusterAllReplicas('your-cluster',system.replicas) 
WHERE absolute_delay > 0
```